# Отключить Menu Bar на совсем в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Как отключить Menu Bar `|File|Edit|etc|` в Sublime Text 3 на совсем?
Такая проблема: забиндил тоггл меню на ctrl+alt+m, и спокойно могу переключать его видимость, но если я alt+tab'нусь на другое окно, а потом так же обратно, то меню опять появляется. Это не то что бы великая проблема, но довольно таки раздражает, мне что, каждый раз после альтаба опять его выключать? А переключаю окна часто же. Как отключить эту функцию ALT'a в ST3?

Comment: [**Не воспроизводится**](http://i.imgur.com/pbqs7hk.gif) в Windows 10 Education, Menu Bar не появляется после `Alt+Tab`. Укажите, пожалуйста, свою операционную систему. Связывали ли самостоятельно с `Alt+Tab` какую-то команду? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, ноутбук, WinXP (Нету возможности выше, ибо это максимум что он терпит.
WinXP SP3 + ST3 + Soda Light Theme